# Gnome terminal tab crashes in vim through some as yet unknown key trigger

Tags: gnome-terminal

I haven't got the magic combination yet to reproduce but it happens fairly often that gnome terminal tabs crash/freeze while editing files in vim. I need to shut down the tab/session.

Not sure yet on the key press but if anyone has ideas on how to debug that would be useful.

This has happened on ubuntu 18.04 and now on 19.10 after upgrading still.

Comment: Is it possibly `Ctrl+S`? If so, do you get it to unfreeze with `Ctrl+Q`?

Comment: Just hit it again and Ctrl+S (maybe) but definitely Ctrl+Q seemed to get me out of the freeze.

Comment: i'm on chromebook terminal which is a flavor of gnome-terminal. and i noticed the same thing. to reproduce the issue i have found that i: open the terminal, maximize, cd /to/a/project, vim project_file, in vim search with / for estimat and it happens. my gnome-terminal kicks out. my typing goes back to another GUI and i see "tim". so i know that in vim the keystroke is `/es`.

Comment: this time i resized the window from the default terminal width and height and it crashed out. so it's not anything to do with maximize. something else.

Comment: i installed mate-terminal and now i don't get the issue. so... there's that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got hit with the same.  Go to the Terminal pull down and uncheck the Read-Only box.  No idea how it suddenly got set in the middle of editing a file with vi.  Seems like a really bad feature.  Now if there was just a way to disable the "X" close tab function or add a confirmation do you really want do do this.